# increment info of Node in tree with 100

Tags: increment

i have a problem with increment values in binary Tree with 100, i need to increment only the leaf in the Tree
example: if i have node with info=66,,, after increment with 100 --- it should be 166 if it's leaf.
see the below code i tried with:

```
 void BinaryTree::incrementLeaves (BTNode *rootNode, int el){
    return incrementLeavesImpl (rootNode, el);
}
void BinaryTree::incrementLeavesImpl (BTNode *rootNode, int el){
    if (rootNode==0) return 0;
    int value =100;
    if (el->isLeftLeaf() && el->isRightLeaf())
    {value =100;} else {value =0;}
    return value +incrementLeavesImpl(isLeaf());

    }
```

could you please advise why this is not working with me.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VOID function cannot return a value.